# django inlineformset throws IndexError: list index out of range on save

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views, inline-formset

So this one killed me for a day and I still don't know why my solution works. I thought I would share it in case someone comes across this.
Django 1.6

I have a FormView and a form and inlineformset.
I'm handling the post myself

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    foo_form = self.form_class(self.request.POST)    
    if foo_form.is_valid():
        foo = foo_form.save(commit=False)        

        bar_formset = BarInlineFormset(self.request.POST, instance=foo)                
        if bar_formset.is_valid():
            foo.save()
            bar_formset.save()

            # redirect here
            return HttpResponseRedirect('whatever')


    kwargs['form'] = foo_form
    # in my get_context_data I'm setting context['bar_formset'] if i pass it in as a kwarg so errors from the articleformset are retained
    kwargs['bar_formset'] = bar_formset
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)    

    return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)
```

This works for creating brand new foo. but as soon as you try to edit a foo or it's corresponding bars, you will get a
**IndexError: list index out of range.**
The error in fact is exactly the same as
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15574

Reading through the bug however, the symptoms are not the same at all -- i.e there is no concurrent editing of an object going on, there is no deletion or change of relations going on.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a full day including going through django source code, not comming up with anything, I thought I might be making a mistake by setting the instance to the new as-yet unsaved foo.

So I simply went and changed the instance to an actual foo if we are editing an existing foo and all is right with the world again. =\

I assume that the fact the instance hasn't been committed is why the inlineformset is barfing but I don't know specifically why. Maybe someone can help shed some light in the comments

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        foo = Foo.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    except KeyError:
        foo = Foo()
    foo_form = self.form_class(self.request.POST, instance=foo)            
    bar_formset = BarInlineFormset(self.request.POST, instance=foo_form.instance)                
    if foo_form.is_valid() and bar_formset.is_valid():
            foo_form.save()
            bar_formset.save()

            # redirect here
            return HttpResponseRedirect('whatever')


    kwargs['form'] = foo_form
    # in my get_context_data I'm setting context['bar_formset'] if i pass it in as a kwarg so errors from the articleformset are retained
    kwargs['bar_formset'] = bar_formset
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)    

    return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)
```

Comment: man i am so dumb. I should just be using the instance on the form object. edited answer accordingly.

Comment: wow i'm just.... a moron today. I think the root cause of the issue is that I wasn't instantiating the form with an instance of foo. I was assuming the form on the page was rendered with an id field, but it wasn't.